# Azure CI/D Build Pipeline not building all projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a repo with 4 projects, 2 class libraries, 1 asp.net core project and 1 console.exe project

When I run the following, it only builds a zip for the asp.net core project.  I would like it to also build a zip for the console app

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
  inputs:
    version: 5.0.x
    performMultiLevelLookup: true
    includePreviewVersions: true # Required for preview versions

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Publish"
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    arguments: '-r win-x64 --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: "Upload Artifacts"
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

**EDIT:**
Based on @DreadedForet's code, here is what is produced
that created with 1 zip (job) with the following in it:

1. Test Results  - empty
2. a - contains zip for the web project (this is
   correct)
3. b - empty
4. s - seems to be a dump of all the projects source
   code (content of the dir that the .sln is in)

Comment: Hi @Zoinky, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You only have a publish task for the DotNetCore project.  If wanting to publish all the files in an Azure Pipline try replacing the PublishBuildArtifacts@1 task with PublishPipelineArtifact@1 like this.  This may not accomplish 100% of what you are trying but should help.

```
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    #targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)' 
    #artifactName: 'drop'
```

This will publish everything connected to your pipeline as opposed to just those that have been pushed to the staging directory.

Comment: see edit of the OP, FYI the web project is a .net 5 project, and so is the console (not sure if that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0):

We can disable the option `Publish web projects` and add specify the project path, such as below.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'project path'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: "Upload Artifacts"
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Then add the task again to build a zip for the console app